# Java number triangle in decreasing order

Tags: java

I need to produce  a triangle like:

```
6
55
444
3333
22222
111111
```

This is my code:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= size+1; row++) {

    for (int col = 1; col <= size+1 - row ; col++) 
    {
        System.out.print(row);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

which produces an upside down triangle.

Comment: so use a decreasing loop... `row = 6; row > 0; row--`

Comment: ...and then print `(size + 1 - row)` rather than `row`. Also, what are the tab characters supposed to do? They aren't in evidence in the sample output you posted.

Comment: tab character is just for spacing. if spacing not wanted remove the "\t" or tab character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the desired results:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= size; row++) {
    for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++) {
        System.out.print((size - row + 1) + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

You'll need to remove the tab character though to get the results posted above.

Answer (score -1):

This will help

```
int num=size;
    for(int i=1;i<=size;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(num);
        }
        System.out.println();
        num--;
    }
```

Comment: But *how* does it help?  Merely putting a chunk of code as an answer is untenable since it doesn't explain what the problem is.

Comment: What is the purpose of declaring another variable? You could reuse size instead of declaring another variable.